# How can I pass multiple parameters separated with a ? and & using AngularJS $resource?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following action in an AngularJS $resource

```
getEntity: { url: '/api/:entityType/:entityId', method: 'GET' },
```

This sends something like the following to my server:

```
/api/xxx/123
```

I would now like to make it so the server receives:

```
/api/xxx?subjectId=12&contentTypeId=23
```

Here is where I am calling the getEntity:

```
        getEntity: function (entityType, entityId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            EntityResource.getEntity({ entityType: entityType, entityId: entityId },
               function (resp) {
                   deferred.resolve(resp);
               }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Can someone show me how I can do this.

Comment: If possible can someone provide a complete answer so I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add query parameters to the object parameter, i.e.:

```
getEntity: function (entityType, entityId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            EntityResource.getEntity({ entityType:
               entityType, entityId: entityId, subjectId:12, contentTypeId:23 },
               function (resp) {
                   deferred.resolve(resp);
               }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Look at the parameters section in the AngularJS [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) for an explanation.

Comment: But don't I have to also make a change to the action which is "getEntity: { url: '/api/:entityType/:entityId', method: 'GET' },"

Comment: The values in the object you pass are bound to as many as action parameters being in the resource url, the remaining are passed as query parameters, it's clearly explained in the documentation section I quoted.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help but I am sorry I think before I accept I should wait for an answer that shows this. I don't think it's fair for others who might look at the question if I was to accept with the answer still not quite finished and a message saying to look in the documents.

Comment: Okay so you are saying I won't need to make a change to the getEntity: on the second line of the question. That's great. I will check that out.